# How to get the string input content from JsonSerializationException?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I was trying to de-serialize stream content from HttpResponseMessage. In try-catch block I can trace the exception but not able get the response data (input of deserialization). I need that for debugging purpose. Here is my code

```
   try
        {
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                   {
                      using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                      {
                          var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                          return serializer.Deserialize<Product>(jsonTextReader);
                      }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
        {
            // I need to get the string content of the input data in case of exception occurs
        }
```

Comment: It's impossible. You are not even deserializing from String, you are deserializing from Stream, Which is not converted to string during serialization, because if it did, it would cause performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your product class fields are public?
I don't use your json package serial/deserializer, but i wasn't able to parse the information because by classes had private fields.

Comment: yes my Product class has all the required public fields. The problem is that is somehow there is invalid json in stream then that will not parse correctly. And I need that string in exception

Comment: try to write: YourMethod([FromBody] object request) and then convert the object into a string

Comment: sorry I don't get you

Comment: In your API call method declaration, write this statement:
YourMethod([FromBody] object request)

Comment: I am consuming the API and the API did not have any problem. It is returning the correct data. Problem is in the serialization. If somehow it get failed I want to track the input string

Comment: i got it, i had a similar problem as well.But the only way i was able to get the request as a string was this one, and you get only the body from this.